# Style a layer based on an attribute from GeoServer in OpenLayers 3

Tags: geoserver, javascript, openlayers, style

I want to take attribute from field_1 in GeoServer to show in OpenLayers 3

This is the script:

```
var style_titik =(
if (feature.get('field_6') === '4')
{var b2 = new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Circle({
                radius: 6,
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: 'rgba(20,150,200,0.6)'
                }),
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: 'rgba(20,130,150,0.8)',
                    width: 1
                })
            })
})});   
else {      var b1 = new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Circle({
                radius: 30,
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: 'rgba(255,1,2,0.6)'
                }),
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: 'rgba(220,1,1,0.8)',
                    width: 1
                })
            })
})};
```

What about this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using a [style function](http://openlayers.org/ol3-workshop/vector-style/style-intro.html) (see also the OL3 Example on [Earthquake Clusters](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.1/examples/earthquake-clusters.html?q=style%20function) for a more detailed example of a style function - or search this site!).  In your case, partial code would be along the lines of:

```
var myStyleFunction = function(feature, resolution){
    var field_1 = feature.get('field_1');
    if (field_1 == "PENYEDIA AKOMODASI"){
        return b1;
    } else if (field_1 == "JASA PENYEDIA AKOMODASI"){
        return b2;
    }
};

var lokasipenting = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: lokasi_penting,
    style: myStyleFunction
});
```

Note that you will have to define styles b1 and b2 and that is the best place to set the name as part of the text attribute.  The simplest way to do that is create a text variable (e.g. `var myText = new ol.style.text` etc.) and then include that in b1 and b2 to save duplication.  Alternatively you could have a single return (which is probably better) and use variables to create the equivalents of b1 and b2 as per the examples in the links.

**EDIT (update based on comment)**
For each map refresh, OL iterates over the features in the data it has received from Geoserver and calls the style function.  It automatically passes these two values for each feature and that's why you don't see any reference to them in the layer definition.  The 'feature' is a point, linestring or polygon (or their multi equivalents) from the layer's data and the resolution is the resolution of the map (allowing you to have zoom-based styling too).

Comment: can you explain,    function(feature, resolution)

Comment: See my edits above

Answer (score 2):

```
function getStyle(feature, resolution){
    var style;
    if (feature.get('field_6') === '4')
        style = new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Circle({
                radius: 6,
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: 'rgba(20,150,200,0.6)'
                }),
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: 'rgba(20,130,150,0.8)',
                    width: 1
                })
            })
        })
    else
        style = new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Circle({
                radius: 30,
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: 'rgba(255,1,2,0.6)'
                }),
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: 'rgba(220,1,1,0.8)',
                    width: 1
                })
            })
        })
    return [style];
}
myLayer = ol.layer.Vector({
    store: ...,
    style: getStyle
});
```